# Can someone please check my noob VAR formula?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I've recently started working through the book "The Definitive Guide to DAX", but got stuck at one of the examples.

**Data in visual:**
Delivery Date    01/08/2007
SalesAmount  $7,530.881
TotalCost    $3,947.08
GrossMargin     $3,583.801
**Var GrosMarg%* 5.31**

(Link to picture of visual with data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xv2irn53zftdu9qn1njtcreyOK8nKQkO/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, Var GrosMarg% is not correct. It's definitely not 5%, or 530% (which I get when I format it as a %).

But I really see nothing wrong with my VAR calculation:

```
Var GrosMarg% = 
VAR TotalSales = sum(Sales[SalesAmount])
VAR TotalCosts = sum(Sales[TotalCost])
VAR GrossMargin = TotalSales - TotalCosts

Return 
GrossMargin / TotalSales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAX logic is correct. The only problem I can think is that you are creating a Column instead of a Measure. If that the case the results should be diferent.

As an example I created a column and a measure so you can see the diference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I used a measure and indeed got the right answer. Is there perhaps a rule of thumb when you should use a measure and when a column? like, when calculating total sales a column, when calculating percentages a measure?